# How do I map a keyboard as a joystick device in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, game-controller, controller

Well my laptop has a Nintendo DS emulator, which of course I can play NDS games in with the keyboard but the key mappings are limited to only A-Z and arrow keys.

There is an option to enable a joystick.. which I don't have.

I have a second keyboard lying around which I can connect.. but I do not want Windows to detect it as a keyboard but as a Joystick.

How do I trick windows into thinking I'm connecting a 115 button joystick?

It's a usb keyboard so I think it's possible? (and still be able to use my laptops' keyboard normally)

Comment: why not just buy a cheap USB joystick or gamepad?

Comment: yeah I can go and buy one but would be interesting if this is possible